# Angularjs ng-click on repeat table row not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-click on the following HTML is not working for me in AngularJS

```
<tr ng-repeat="ai in alert_instances" ng-click="go('/alert_instance/{{ai.alert_instancne_id}}')">
  <td>{{ai.name}}</td>
  <td>{{ai.desc}}</td>
</tr>
```

The "go" function in my controller at the moment just has

```
$scope.go = function (hash) {
  console.log("hi")
};
```

Comment: Should it be {go('..')} . teh angularjs docs say <ANY ng-click="{expression}">

Comment: hm.. that's not working for me either...

Comment: Does `ng-click="go('/alert_instance/' + ai.alert_instancne_id)"` work?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. You shouldn't be using curly braces in Angular directives (`ng-click`), as this syntax is aimed for templates.

A proper way:

```
<tr ng-repeat="ai in alert_instances" ng-click="go(ai)">
  <td>{{ai.name}}</td>
  <td>{{ai.desc}}</td>
</tr>

$scope.go = function(ai) {
  var hash = '/alert_instance/' + ai.alert_instancne_id;
  //...
};
```