# Ng-click not up to date?

Tags: angularjs, function, button, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-click

I have a select of users and based on the selected user it shows certain buttons. The button their titles and id's are in objects that come from ng-repeat. When clicked on a button it passes an id to a function. As test I put the id passed to the button in the button title and alert the passed id in the function. Whenever I switch to the second user the id in the title is correct but the alert in the function is the id of the previous selected user. Here some code:

```
<div class="ShapeTableRow" ng-repeat="selfShape in employeeShapes.self">
    <button ng-if="selfShape.clickable === true" id="{{selfShape.shapeClass}}" class="button" ng-click="goToCriteria({{selfShape.id}});">{{selfShape.title}}{{selfShape.id}}</button>
</div>

$scope.goToCriteria = function (shapeIndex) {
    alert(shapeIndex);
};
```

So the ng-repeat object is basically up to date but not the value alerted in the function.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: [Angularjs ng-click on repeat table row not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15288047/angularjs-ng-click-on-repeat-table-row-not-working) the curly braces made sure the id stayed the same.